# rails 3 + devise: how change a flash message NOT in locale file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My rails 3 app uses devise, and we have it set so a user gets emailed a confirmation token.

As soon as a user signs up, devise 'flashes' the following prompt which I need to change:

```
You have signed up successfully. However, we could not 
sign you in because your account is unconfirmed.
```

This message is not in the devise.en.yaml file...

Does anyone know how to change this flash message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `inactive_signed_up` in `config/locales/devise.en.yml`:

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      inactive_signed_up: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is %{reason}.'
```

Comment: HOW in the world did you know that? Is there some list of such things I can review?

Comment: also, do you know if there is a way to embed %{the_email_address_user_registered} in that flash message so it can say "we sent a confirmation email to YOUREMAIL@WHATEVER.COM... please lcik the confirmation link"

Comment: I searched the (downloaded) source code of devise for it and found it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml#L35). Not sure if you can add email to the flash, with the current code, but you can try overriding the controller. [Some code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L22)

Comment: This *really* should be on their wiki. Searching through source code isn't acceptable documentation.